# Are there some types of investment that can return 5% per year and is anti-inflation?

Tags: stocks, investing, dividends

Some people claimed that if a person has a million dollars (US$1 million), and spend $4000 per month, which is $48,000 or roughly $50,000 a year, then after 20 years, the person is broke (has no money).

Are there fairly safe investment types that can return 5% (such as dividend) per year, and is anti-inflation?  If there are, then it can return $50,000 each year and can grow together with inflation, so that 20 years later, it is still $1 million but in future value (which is $1.8 million if assuming a 3% inflation).

Comment: "5% per year and is anti-inflation" means **8% per year** (given your assumption of 3% inflation).

Comment: @RonJohn Technically, it's multiplicative, not additive. So it's (1.05)*(1.03) = 1.0815, or 8.15%.

Comment: @Acccumulation "technically correct... the best kind of correct!"  To that, I'd say, "close enough for government work".  :)

Answer (score 4):

You can buy inflation-protected securities in some countries. In the US they're called Treasury Inflation-Protected Securities or [TIPS](https://www.treasurydirect.gov/indiv/research/indepth/tips/res_tips_rates.htm).  In the UK they're called inflation-linked GILTs. With these securities, the principal amount increases by the level of "inflation", typically measured as a change in the Consumer Price Index (CPI).

Unfortunately they don't pay out anywhere near 5% right now - current real yields for TIPS are between 3 and 50 basis points depending on how long you tie your money up for (5 years to 30 years). So you would have to sell back some of your bonds each year . They're not meant for income; they're meant to protect your principal amount from inflation.

A better option would be to take some risk and invest in something that grows at 5% *plus* your expectation of future inflation. So if you think inflation will be at about 3% going forward, then find investments that pay about 8% *on average*. If your investment horizon is 20 years, you can afford to take some risk, earning more than 8% in some years and less than 8% in others.

Answer (score 1):

**Quick Summary**

It depends on how lucky you are.  Based on on analysis of historical data, there is roughly

- a 20% probability that you'd be either out of money or have fewer than 5 years of remaining withdrawls left
- a 40% probability that you'd have enough left to continue funding that income stream for another 5 to 20 years (your portfolio would have declined in real value but would still be reasonably substantial)
- a 40% probability that you'd be able to continue funding that income stream basically indefinitely (your portfolio would have grown in real value over the 20 years, often significantly)

**Detail**

This basically boils down to the question of "what is a safe withdrawl rate".  That is, given a lump sum, how much can you withdraw every year, indexed to inflation, and be comfortable that you'll be able to continue withdrawing money until you die.

There is no single answer to this question because a great deal depends on luck-- if you start withdrawing just before a major market drop, you're in a much worse position than if you get a bunch of good years initially before a late market correction-- as well as things like asset allocation.  Generally, it is phrased in terms of probabilities-- what are the odds that your portfolio will last n years given an x% withdrawl rate given historical trends.

If you want to get deep in the weeds, you can look at William Bengen's original paper [Determining Withdrawl Rates Using Historical Data](http://www.retailinvestor.org/pdf/Bengen1.pdf) which works through a bunch of scenarios.  The upshot of that paper, though, was a recommendation that you limit yourself to a 4% withdrawl rate ($40,000 per year from a $1 million portfolio indexed to inflation) because that was historically safe.  Broadly, you'll find people suggesting safe withdrawl rates between 3% and 4.5% depending on various assumptions.

Withdrawing 5% ($50,000 per year from your 1% portfolio indexed to inflation) is aggressive but if you only need the withdrawls to last 20 years, is probably safe.  One of the graphs in Bengen's paper (Figure 1(c)) shows how many years a 50% stock portfolio lasted historically with a 5% withdrawl rate

[image: Number of Years Portfolio Assets Will Last With a 5% Withdrawl Rate]

Such a portfolio always lasted at least 20 years though occasionally only barely.  In a number of cases, the portfolio would have been exhausted after another couple years-- you wouldn't be broke but you'd have way less than the original $1 million.  If you planned on needing to continue relying on income from that money, you'd be in pretty bad shape.

Looking at the graph, in about 40% of the cases, after 20 years of withdrawls, you'd be able to get at least 30 more years of income.  I'd wager in most of those cases, the portfolio had grown enough in the early years that you'd be able to continue drawing that income basically indefinitely.  In about 20% of the cases, you'd either be out of money or within a handful of years of running out.  And in the remaining 40%, you'd be able to continue withdrawing the income for between 5 and 20 additional years before the portfolio was exhausted.

Whether those are "good" odds, of course, depends heavily on your personal situation.  If you're a 20 year old that won the lottery and is thinking of retiring and living on the money for the rest of your life, you're looking at a 60% chance of running out of money before you hit retirement age.  If you're an 80 year old looking for retirement income, though, getting "only" 20-25 years is pretty good.

Of course, Bengen's original paper is rather old.  Others have looked at more recent market data and different portfolios to see how different asset allocations and withdrawl rates have worked historically.  That's part of why there are different recommendations for safe withdrawl rates.  5% is aggressive but not completely absurd depending on how lucky you feel.

Answer (score 1):

> Some people claimed that if a person has a million dollars (US$1 million), and spend $4000 per month, which is $48,000 or roughly $50,000 a year, then after 20 years, the person is broke (has no money).

If you have $1 million and you spend $50k a year (5% withdrawal rate), assuming that there's no growth, your money lasts 20 years.  It's not a claim.  It's a fact.  Your money lasts 20 years.

Long term CDs currently pay about 2% a year.  To simplify, if we pretend there are no taxes, your money now lasts 25+ years.  Bump that to 4% yield and your money lasts 42 years.

> Are there fairly safe investment types that can return 5% per year, and is anti-inflation? If there are, then it can return $50,000 each year and can grow together with inflation, so that 20 years later, it is still $1 million but in future value (which is $1.8 million if assuming a 3% inflation).

8% a year is possible but a lot of achieving that is dependent on what the market does in the early years.  Sequence risk is the danger that when you begin withdrawals, the market corrects and your money does not compound in the early years.

For something reasonably safe but falling short of your objective, I'd offer investment grade preferred stocks.  The five major Preferred stock ETFs currently pay about 5.4% yield.  That would yield about $1.13 million in 20 years.  Here's a chart from 2017 showing the yields for that time period:

[image]

And here's a 2017 chart of the annualized returns of these five ETFs, some going back as much as 10 years ago.

[image: Annual Return]

There are risks with preferred stocks but unless there's further interest in this, I'll leave it at that.